# Should I JOIN or should I UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I have four different tables I am trying to query on, the first table is where I will be doing most of the querying, but if there is no match in car I am to look in other fields in the other tables to see if there is a match from a VIN parameter.

Example:

```
Select 
    c.id,
    c.VIN,
    c.uniqueNumber,
    c.anotheruniqueNumber
FROM Cars c, Boat b
WHERE
    c.VIN = @VIN(parameter),
    b.SerialNumber = @VIN
```

Now say that I have no match in `Cars`, but there is a match in `Boat`, how would I be able to pull the matching Boat record vs the car record?  I have tried to JOIN the tables, but the tables have no unique identifier to reference the other table.

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to search all the tables off of a parameter but with the least amount of code.  I thought about doing `UNION ALL`, but not sure if that what I really want for this situation, seeing as the number of records could get extremely large.

I am currently using `SQL Server 2012`.  Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED:**

```
CAR table
ID  VIN               UniqueIdentifier      AnotherUniqueIdentifier
1   2002034434        HH54545445            2016-A23
2   2002035555        TT4242424242          2016-A24
3   1999034534        AGH0000034            2016-A25


BOAT table
ID  SerialNumber    Miscellaneous
1   32424234243     545454545445
2   65656565656     FF24242424242
3   20023232323     AGH333333333
```

Expected Result if `@VIN` parameter matches a Boat identifier:

```
BOAT
ID  SerialNumber    Miscellaneous
2   65656565656     FF24242424242
```

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help

Comment: Typically `JOIN` is used for data that has a defined relationship. eg: Courses and Students.  Short of possibly Cars Towing Boats there is no referential relationship so a `JOIN` would not apply here.

Comment: Please please please, stop using that outdated [join syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Simlpy write two queries, Q1 selects from `cars` and if it returns no row Q2 selects from `boats`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sort of `union all` might be the best approach -- at least the fastest with the right indexes:

```
Select c.id, c.VIN, c.uniqueNumber, c.anotheruniqueNumber
from Cars c
where c.VIN = @VIN
union all
select b.id, b.VIN, b.uniqueNumber, b.anotheruniqueNumber
from Boats b
where b.VIN = @VIN and
      not exists (select 1 from Cars C where c.VIN = @VIN);
```

This assumes that you have the corresponding columns in each of the tables (which your question implies is true).

The chain of `not exists` can get longer as you add more entity types.  A simple way around is to do sorting instead -- assuming you want only one row:

```
select top 1 x.*
from (Select c.id, c.VIN, c.uniqueNumber, c.anotheruniqueNumber, 1 as priority
      from Cars c
      where c.VIN = @VIN
      union all
      select b.id, b.VIN, b.uniqueNumber, b.anotheruniqueNumber, 2 as priority
      from Boats b
      where b.VIN = @VIN 
     ) x
order by priority;
```

There is a slight overhead for the `order by`.  But frankly speaking, ordering 1-4 rows is trivial from a performance perspective.

Comment: That's assuming that `Boats` and `Cars` have the same columns, but +1 anyways.

Comment: How effective would it be to add `NULL`s to the the columns that don't match up? Because like I said I would be querying mostly on `Cars` and not the other tables as frequently. Would adding `NULL`s to the other tables in UNION cause any issues?

Comment: @programmer117 . . . If a column is not present in the other tables then definitely use `NULL` as a place holder.